# AutodiscoverLocalException: The Autodiscover service couldn't be located

Tags: c#, .net, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to access exchange server by using .NET 3.5. Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("email_test@xxx.com", "abcd");

            service.AutodiscoverUrl("email_test@xxx.com");

            EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
            message.Subject = "Interesting";
            message.Body = "The proposition has been considered.";
            message.ToRecipients.Add("abc@xxx.com");
            message.SendAndSaveCopy();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I am referring [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633626%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) to write the codes:

But I receive this exception:

> AutodiscoverLocalException: The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it was due the user account being locked out.

Answer (score 1):

```
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("<loginID..not email address>", "< the pw>");
service.AutodiscoverUrl("<your emailaddress>",RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.